# Did well or Have done well?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

So I've been wondering which one sounds more natural if I want to compliment someone for something they have done? Do they have different meanings? Or perhaps they can be used interchangeably?

> Good job, you did well

or

> Good job, you have done well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple past **did** is used about something that was completed at some point in the past.

The present perfect **have done** is used about something that started some time ago and is still happening, or was completed some time ago but has a lasting effect.

In your example with did/have done, both are OK and there is not much difference between them. You might be more likely to use **did** if you are talking about a single action in the past and **have done** if the activity took some time extending until now, and/or it is expected to continue.

The difference is more noticable with a word like **work**:

> I worked there for five years (but I no longer do) - *past simple*
>  
>   I have worked there for five years (and I still do) - *present perfect*

and **reserve**

> I reserved a room (and then I cancelled the reservation) - *past simple*
>   I have reserved a room (and the reservation still stands) - *present perfect*